# How to add a sequence column to an existing table with records

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I had created a new table named USERLOG with two fields from a previous VIEW. The table already consist of about 9000 records. The two fields taken from the VIEW, i.e. weblog_views consist of IP (consists of IP address), and WEB_LINK (consists of URL). This is the code I used,

```
    CREATE TABLE USERLOG
    AS
    SELECT C_IP, WEB_LINK FROM weblog_views;
```

I want to add another column to this table called the USER_ID, which would consists of a sequence starting with 1 to 9000 records to create a unique id for each existing rows. I need help with this part. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer: ODMiner version 3.0.04. 
I tried using the AUTO-INCREMENT option,

```
    ALTER TABLE USERLOG
    ADD USER_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

But I get an error with this,

```
    Error report:
    SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
    01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
```

So, I would really appreciate any help that I can get!

Answer (score 61):

You would need to add a column

```
ALTER TABLE userlog
  ADD( user_id number );
```

create a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

Update the data in the table

```
UPDATE userlog
   SET user_id = user_id_seq.nextval
```

Assuming that you want `user_id` to be the primary key, you would then add the primary key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE userlog
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY( user_id );
```

If you want to use the sequence to automatically add the `user_id` when you do an `INSERT` (the other option would be to specifically reference `user_id_seq.nextval` in your `INSERT` statements, you would also need a trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_userlog_user_id
  BEFORE INSERT ON userlog
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.user_id := user_id_seq.nextval;
END;
```

Comment: +1 for: beat me to it, better answer than I would have given, and not using the `SELECT ... FROM dual` syntax in the trigger.

Comment: I needed to use the `SELECT user_id_seq.nextval INTO :new.user_id FROM DUAL;` syntax in the trigger, because my ORACLE version didn't like the `:new.user_id := user_id_seq.nextval;` syntax. :(

Comment: I am late to the party here, but instead of a trigger you can set a default value:  `alter table userlog modify(user_id default user_id_seq.nextval);`  There is a danger to doing it this way: a programmer could create an insert statement with an incorrect value for user_id.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1.
Create sequence to be used by the column
eg:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

Step 2.
Update new column with sequence
eg:

```
UPDATE userlog
   SET user_id = user_id_seq.nextval;
```

Step 3. - Set Sequence as the default value for the column, will work only above Oracle 12c

```
ALTER TABLE USERLOG
    MODIFY USER_ID INT DEFAULT user_id_seq.nextval;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Justin's excellent answer you might want to prevent NULL values for your user_id in the future (as they could still be caused by UPDATE statements). Therefore, execute the following statement at the end:

`ALTER TABLE userlog MODIFY(user_id number NOT NULL);`